# How to use a quoted string variable in a MySqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sorry if this seems a really stupid question, but I'm struggling to get to grips with changing from Mysql to Mysqli and prepared statements.

So in mysql, I would have done this:

```
$q=('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field="'.$variable.'"');
$result = mysql_query($q);
```

I now know this is not good. So I now have the below:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $variable);
$stmt->execute();
```

Problem is that the query doesn't work. Say the ? is actually "tree". So the query becomes:

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=tree LIMIT 1'
```

If I tried to run that query in say phpmyadmin I get "Unknown column tree in where clause". Obviously if I put quotes around it then it works, hence the original query. So how can I get this to work if I can't use quotes, since then you are looking for the literal question mark?

For reference I am then using this code:

```
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
  $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  foreach($row as $key => $val) {
    $x[$key] = $val;
  }
  $results[] = $x;
}
```

As I can't use get_result() which is very annoying. I have PHP version 5.4, and even the mysqlnd driver, but can't enable it as I'm on a VPS and my host says it might affect other sites on that server. Consequently what is actually just two lines in MySql is actually now something like 15 lines in the 'improved' mysqli. Great.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: all your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: You should add error handling. Add this to the top of the script to have mysqli throw exceptions: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: To downvoters, sorry if you feel my post is not helpful or relevant, I am just trying to understand something which I'm finding frustrating and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $variable);
```

is ***not*** equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=tree LIMIT 1
```

Prepared statement placeholders are not the same as copy and pasting in values. You are binding the value `"tree"` as a string here, the database will actually understand this. The `?` is not simply being replaced by the bound value, the database understands the difference between your *query structure* with its placeholders and the *values* you're binding into them. Binding the parameter this way is equivalent to running:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='tree' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think I understand, that actually the top query you mentioned there is equivalent to the bottom one, and that the quotes are implied. When I just tried to get one field, the query worked as I expected when doing a `bind_param`, `execute`, `bind_result` and then `fetch`. It just seems a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

> Consequently what is actually just two lines in MySql is actually now something like 15 lines in the 'improved' mysqli. Great.

Mysqli is not intended to be used as is. It is but a building material for the higher level library. When used *wisely*, it can give you data in *one* line:

```
$data = $db->getAll('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=?s', $variable);
```

(BTW, the same goes for the old mysql ext as well)

Comment: Is getAll() part of PHP?

Comment: I can assure you it is not Java.

Comment: I asked that as when I tried to use it I got an undefined error. However further looking into it has lead me to PEAR, which I didn't know about, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: This was just an example, to illustrate what I am talking about. But it seems you don't want to read but want just a solution that will make things easy for you by some magic, without any effort. Well then, move to PDO. It is not as good but it offers some remedy the way you want it - out of the box.

Comment: This is not an answer, and @YourCommonSense is more condescending in nature than the usefulness of his own post. I shall take that 1 point from you due to your badly written "example". Quote: "it can give you data in one line".